# How to center the content in the head of a longtable?

Tags: tables, longtable

I use package `longtable` to make a table as follows.  Please help to center the content in the first head and the head of the table. Thanks!

```
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\tablename{Appendix}
\begin{longtable}{| p{0.3 \textwidth} | p{0.6 \textwidth} |}
\caption{\bf Outline of PS(V) 1.8c-12} \label{appendix2} \\
\hline  \ PS(V) 1.8c-12 & Outline} \\ \hline \hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{}: Outline of PS(V) 1.8c-12}} \\
\hline {PS{V} 1.8c-12} & {Outline} \\ \hline \hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{\tiny Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot
\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments and suggestions:

- Don't embed a `longtable` environment inside a `center` environment -- the `longtable` is automatically centered horizontally.
- By "center the content in the first head", I assume you wish to achieve horizontal centering. If that's correct, simply add `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{...}` wrappers for the first column headers and `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` for the second.

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\tablename{Appendix}
\begin{longtable}{| p{0.3\textwidth} | p{0.6\textwidth} |}
\caption{\bf Outline of PS(V) 1.8c-12} \label{appendix2} \\
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{PS(V) 1.8c-12} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Outline} \\ 
\hline \hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\tablename\ \thetable: Outline of PS(V) 1.8c-12} \\
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{PS(V) 1.8c-12} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Outline} \\ 
\hline \hline
\endhead

\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{\tiny Continued on next page} \\ 
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\hline
123 & abc \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```